# how to sort products based on category

Tags: javascript, arrays, ionic-framework

Can some please help me with some code, I'm building a shopping list app. So I have an array of products, inside each product object there's a category name. what I want to do is display product under each category using ngFor, like category name fresh food under it everything with fresh food gets displayed so on. here is my array:

```
var products = [{
    "id": "219",
    "product_id": "198909",
    "sku": "20148089",
    "prod_name": "Chocolate Mousse 1L",
    "vendor": "Woolworths",
    "price": "45.09",
    "status": "0",
    "category": "Bakery & Desserts"
}, {
    "id": "220",
    "product_id": "199403",
    "sku": "20008307",
    "prod_name": "Medium Carrots 500g",
    "vendor": "Woolworths",
    "price": "10.99",
    "status": "0",
    "category": "Carrots & Beetroot"
}, {
    "id": "221",
    "product_id": "204759",
    "sku": "6009207908908",
    "prod_name": "Fresh Spicy Lentil & Vegetable Soup 600g",
    "vendor": "Woolworths",
    "price": "40.78",
    "status": "0",
    "category": "Fresh Food"
}, {
    "id": "222",
    "product_id": "199015",
    "sku": "6009182131643",
    "prod_name": "Bulk White Gouda Cheese 900g",
    "vendor": "Woolworths",
    "price": "126.45",
    "status": "0",
    "category": "Cheese"
}]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and exactly where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have wrong set of data to work with in first place. It should be arrays of categories where each category object contains array of items belongs to category.

But if you can't do anything about data, you need to transform it like this (sorry for TypeScript, it should be the same for JS just without types :) ):

```
// To get categories
let categories: any = {};
products.forEach(product => {

  if (!Object.keys(categories).includes(product.category)) {
    categories[product.category] = {
      items: []
    };
  }
});

// Add items to categories
products.forEach(product => {
  Object.keys(categories).forEach(category => {
    if (product.category === category) {
      categories[category].items.push(product);
    }
  });

});

console.log(categories);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var products = [{ "id": "219",
                     "product_id": "198909", 
                     "sku": "20148089",
                     "prod_name": "Chocolate Mousse 1L",
                     "image_url": "https://www.onecart.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Chocolate-Mousse-1L-20148089.jpg",
                     "vendor": "Woolworths",
                     "price": "45.09", "status": "0", 
                     "category": "Bakery & Desserts" },
                    { "id": "220", "product_id": "199403", 
                     "sku": "20008307",
                     "prod_name": "Medium Carrots 500g",
                     "image_url": "https://www.onecart.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Medium-Carrots-500g-20008307.jpg", 
                     "vendor": "Woolworths",
                     "price": "10.99", "status": "0",
                     "category": "Carrots & Beetroot" },
                    { "id": "221", "product_id": "204759",
                     "sku": "6009207908908",
                     "prod_name": "Fresh Spicy Lentil & Vegetable Soup 600g",
                     "image_url": "https://www.onecart.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Fresh-Spicy-Lentil-Vegetable-Soup-600g-6009207908908-3.jpg",
                     "vendor": "Woolworths",
                     "price": "40.78", "status": "0",
                     "category": "Fresh Food" },
                    { "id": "222", "product_id": "199015",
                     "sku": "6009182131643", 
                     "prod_name": "Bulk White Gouda Cheese 900g",
                     "image_url": "https://www.onecart.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Bulk-White-Gouda-Cheese-900g-6009182131643-1.jpg", 
                     "vendor": "Woolworths", "price": "126.45",
                     "status": "0", "category": "Cheese" }];
    
    function dynamicSort(property) {
        var sortOrder = 1;
    
        if(property[0] === "-") {
            sortOrder = -1;
            property = property.substr(1);
        }
    
        return function (a,b) {
            if(sortOrder == -1){
                return b[property].localeCompare(a[property]);
            }else{
                return a[property].localeCompare(b[property]);
            }        
        }
    }
    
    products.sort(dynamicSort("category"));
    console.log(products.sort(dynamicSort("category")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
products.sort((a,b) => a.category > b.category ? 1 : b.category > a.category ? -1 : 0)
```